# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if' & Uncaught ReferenceError: berechnung is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know, where the problem is, I'm getting two error messages:

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: berechnung is not defined

Do you know what the probem could be? I checked the if function 100 times and the reference of the button, but I have no solution ^^

Thank you!

HTML

```
<body style="background-color:#000000" >

<form>

<p class="titulierung" >Dein Grundbedarf</p>

<p><label for="geschlecht" id="geschlecht">Geschlecht</label>
<select name="geschlecht" size="1" id="geschlecht2">
    <option value="1"> Männlich </option>
    <option value="2"> Weiblich </option>
</select></p>

<p><label for="groesse" id="groesse">Grösse</label>
<input name="groesse" type="number" id="groesse2" placeholder="180"><span class="anhangsel" > cm</span></p>

<p><label for="gewicht" id="gewicht">Gewicht</label>
<input name="gewicht" type="number" id="gewicht2" placeholder="80"> <span class="anhangsel" > kg</span></p>

<p><label for="alter" id="alter">Alter</label>
<input name="alter" type="number" id="alter2" placeholder="25"> <span class="anhangsel" > Jahre</span></p>

<p><label for="zielziel" id="zielziel">Ziel</label>
<select name="zielziel" size="1" id="zielziel2">
    <option value="1"> Gewicht halten </option>
    <option value="0.85"> Abnehmen </option>
    <option value="1.1"> Zunehmen </option>
</select></p>

<p class="angabe" ><span class="ausgabe" >Grundumsatz: <p id="GU1" for="GU1" class="ausgabe2" ></p><span class="anhangsel" > kcal</span></span></p>
</form>

<form>

<p class="titulierung" >Deine Aktivität</p>

<p><label for="akt1" id="akt1">Schlaf</label>
<input name="akt1" type="number" id="akti1" placeholder="8" > <span class="anhangsel" > h</span></p>

<p><label for="akt2" id="akt2">Sitzen, Autofahren, Lesen, Fernsehen</label>
<input name="akt2" type="number" id="akti2" placeholder="8"> <span class="anhangsel" > h</span></p>

<p><label for="akt3" id="akt3">Langsam Gehen, leichte Verrichtungen</label>
<input name="akt3" type="number" id="akti3" placeholder="5"> <span class="anhangsel" > h</span></p>

<p><label for="akt4" id="akt4">Zügig Gehen, körperliche Arbeit</label>
<input name="akt4" type="number" id="akti4" placeholder="3"> <span class="anhangsel" > h</span></p>

<p><label for="akt5" id="akt5">Schwerarbeit, Sport</label>
<input name="akt5" type="number" id="akti5" placeholder="0"> <span class="anhangsel" > h</span></p>


<p><span class="ausgabe" >Total Stunden: <p id="TH1" for="TH1" class="ausgabe2" ></p><span class="anhangsel" > h</span></span></p>
<p><span class="ausgabe" >Durchschnittliche Aktivität pro Tag: <p id="AK1" for="AK1" class="ausgabe2" >0</p><span class="anhangsel" > MET</span></span></p>
<p><span class="ausgabe" >Kalorienverbrauch: <p id="KV1" for="KV1" class="ausgabe2" ></p><span class="anhangsel" > kcal</span></span></p>
<p><span class="ausgabe" >Zielzufuhr: <p id="ZZ1" for="ZZ1" class="ausgabe2" ></p><span class="anhangsel" > kcal</span></span></p>

</form>

<!-- and here on this button I got the message "komplettneuesform.html:222 Uncaught ReferenceError: berechnung is not defined" -->

<button id="btn" onclick="berechnung()">Berechnen</button>

</body>
```

CSS

```
label {
    width: 260px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
}

input {
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px
}

select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

select {
  /* ... */
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/media/305008_53a6e9d4494d496faa8735f0fe0ca330~mv2.png) repeat;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;

}

select {
  /* ... */
  cursor: pointer;
}


select {
    border-style: solid
    border-color: #ddcb07   
}

.titulierung {
    color:white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    }

.ausgabe {
    width: 2600px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    }

.anhangsel, .ausgabe2 {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    }

button {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
}

button {
    background-color: #ddca07; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  height:30px; 
  width:120px; 
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background-color: black; 
  color: white; 
  border: 1px solid #ddca07;
  width:150px;
  height:30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style:bold;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ddca07;
  color: black;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>

function berechnung() {
    var groesse = parseInt(document.getElementById('groesse2').value);
    var gewicht = parseInt(document.getElementById('gewicht2').value);
    var alter = parseInt(document.getElementById('gewicht2').value);
    var geschlecht = parseInt(document.getElementById('geschlecht2').value);
    var geschl1 = (geschlecht === '2') ? 655.1 : 66.47 ;
    var geschl2 = (geschlecht === '2') ? 9.6 : 13.7 ;
    var geschl3 = (geschlecht === '2') ? 1.8 : 5 ;
    var geschl4 = (geschlecht === '2') ? 4.7 : 6.8 ;
    var ziele = parseInt(document.getElementById('zielziel2').value);

    var schlaf = parseInt(document.getElementById('akti1').value);
    var sitzen = parseInt(document.getElementById('akti2').value);
    var gehen1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('akti3').value);
    var gehen2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('akti4').value);
    var sport3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('akti5').value);

    var grundumsatzm = Math.round(66.47 + (13.7 * gewicht) + (5 * groesse) - (6.8 * alter));
    var grundumsatzw = Math.round(655.1 + (9.6 * gewicht) + (1.8 * groesse) - (4.7 * alter));
    var totalstunden = (schlaf + sitzen + gehen1 + gehen2 + sport3);
    var dakt = ((0.9 + 1.2 + 2.2 + 3.3 + 6.6) / 5) ;

    // I'm getting the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if' on this "if":    
    var grundumsatz = if (geschlecht === 1) { 
    Math.round(66.47 + (13.7 * gewicht) + (5 * groesse) - (6.8 * alter));
    } else {
    Math.round(655.1 + (9.6 * gewicht) + (1.8 * groesse) - (4.7 * alter)); 
    };

    var verbrauch = Math.round(grundumsatz * dakt);

    var zielzufuhr = (verbrauch * ziele);

    document.getElementById("GU1").innerHTML = grundumsatz;
    document.getElementById("TH1").innerHTML = totalstunden;
    document.getElementById("AK1").innerHTML = dakt;
    document.getElementById("KV1").innerHTML = verbrauch;
    document.getElementById("ZZ1").innerHTML = zielzufuhr;


    }

</script>
```

Comment: You can't put an `if` statement on the right-hand side of an assignment expression. The error is telling you exactly that.

Comment: As Pointy said, No ''if statements'' after that equal sign. Also, try to start using camelcase when defining two words as variables in your javascript which makes it easier to read, although to be honest I have no clue what that language in those variables mean

Answer (score 2):

You can't put an `if` statement where an expression is required. You can use a conditional (AKA "tertiary") expression.

```
var grundumsatz = geschlecht === 1 ?
    Math.round(66.47 + (13.7 * gewicht) + (5 * groesse) - (6.8 * alter)) :
    Math.round(655.1 + (9.6 * gewicht) + (1.8 * groesse) - (4.7 * alter));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an if statement on the right side of the assignment operator.

Here's a simple solution.

```
let grundumsatz = null;
if (geschlecht === 1) { 
    grundumsatz = Math.round(66.47 + (13.7 * gewicht) + (5 * groesse) - (6.8 * alter));
} else {
    grundumsatz = Math.round(655.1 + (9.6 * gewicht) + (1.8 * groesse) - (4.7 * alter)); 
};
```

You can see that the variable you want to set is declared before the if/else, and then we assign it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer is good, and I'd offer you two additional things:

1. Use `const` for the things are actually const and not representations of mutable state in the underlying domain (shopping cart contents, network connection status cache) (see [this article](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/shun-the-mutant/)  for more detail).
2. Elevate your branches to named constants to make your code more comprehensible ("no magic numbers")

```
const someNamedValue = () =>  Math.round(66.47 + (13.7 * gewicht) + (5 * groesse) - (6.8 * alter))
const someOtherNamedValue = () => Math.round(655.1 + (9.6 * gewicht) + (1.8 * groesse) - (4.7 * alter))

const grundumsatz = geschlecht === 1 ?
    someNamedValue() :
    someOtherNamedValue();
```